# Android:Email: E/AbstractSyncService( 529): java.lang.NullPointerException occurs every time

Tags: android, email, synchronization, httprequest

I am working on Active sync in Android. I get "java.lang.NullPointerException" every time.

Logs shows:

```
Uncaught exception in EasSyncService 
java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:453)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
 at com.android.exchange.EasSyncService.sendHttpClientPost(EasSyncService.java:787)
 at com.android.exchange.EasSyncService.sendPing(EasSyncService.java:721)
 at com.android.exchange.EasSyncService.runPingLoop(EasSyncService.java:1093)
 at com.android.exchange.EasSyncService.runAccountMailbox(EasSyncService.java:957)
 at com.android.exchange.EasSyncService.run(EasSyncService.java:1460)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

This error has been noticed in logs when I am sending http request using POST. Sending the ping command gives the above error some times.

I am not able to figure out why this error occurs and how it can be avoided . Kindly any one can give solution to above and solve the same .

Solution is appreciated well in advance.

Comment: Post the code where you call execute.

Comment: setHeaders(method);
        method.setEntity(entity);
        synchronized(getSynchronizer()) {
            mPendingPost = method;
            if (sleepAllowed) {
                SyncManager.runAsleep(mMailboxId, timeout+(10*SECONDS));
            }
        }
        try {
            return client.execute(method);
        } finally {
            synchronized(getSynchronizer()) {
                if (sleepAllowed) {
                    SyncManager.runAwake(mMailboxId);
                }
                mPendingPost = null;
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

The traceback looks similar to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5255 .